# Couldn't quit R session or couldn't quit RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

New to R and RStudio, got problem in operating RStudio.

I have a code sample about 53 lines, I could quit by typing "q()" or "quit()", 
but after I run any code(selected section or all codes), "q()" will not work as pic showing below
[image]

Or if I try to close RStudio browser, then a notification show up as below but never quit.
[image]

Any hint?

Thanks very much!

PS: RStudio verson: 0.99.948

-----1st Update------
@Mike Wise

Tried to get session info by typing "sessionInfo()" in console,
 unfortunately no response...pic below
[image]

### Again, this case only happens after I run my code

-----2nd Update-------
do the sessionInfo() before you run the code:

Info as below:

> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
>
> locale: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOw7K.jpg) LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOw7K.jpg) stats     graphics  grDevices utils
>   datasets  methods   base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached): [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOw7K.jpg) tools_3.2.3

My code:

```
# Linear Regression in R
# Copyright 2013 by Ani Katchova

mydata <- read.csv(file="E:\\Econometric Academy\\Linear Regression\\regression_auto.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
attach(mydata)

# Define variables
Y <- cbind(mpg)
X1 <- cbind(weight1)
X <- cbind(weight1, price, foreign)

# Descriptive statistics
summary(Y)
summary(X)

# Correlation among variables
cor(Y, X)

# Plotting data on a scatter diagram
plot(Y ~ X1, data = mydata)

# Simple linear regression 
olsreg1 <- lm(Y ~ X1)
summary(olsreg1)
confint(olsreg1, level=0.95)
anova(olsreg1)

# Plotting regression line
abline(olsreg1)

# Predicted values for dependent variable
Y1hat <- fitted(olsreg1)
summary(Y1hat)
plot(Y1hat ~ X1)

# Regression residuals
e1hat <- resid(olsreg1)
summary(e1hat)
plot(e1hat ~ X1)

# Multiple linear regression
olsreg2 <- lm(Y ~ X)
summary(olsreg2)
confint(olsreg2, level=0.95)
anova(olsreg2)

# Predicted values for dependent variable
Yhat <- fitted(olsreg2)
summary(Yhat)

# Regression residuals
ehat <- resid(olsreg2)
summary(ehat)
```

---

Comment: This happens to me now and then. It is probably a bug, maybe an infinite loop in some garbage collector or something. Just kill the process with Task Manager or something.

Comment: Btw, you should post your `sessionInfo()` for this kind of question.

Comment: @MikeWise See my edit

Comment: Post the code you are running. And do the `sessionInfo()` before you run the code.

Comment: @MikeWise Done, 2nd update

Comment: Now try deleting half the code and see if it still hangs. If it does delete half of what is rest. If not add half of what was deleted back. Repeat. This should lead you to figuring out which line is the troublemaker. With less than 32 lines it should take at most 5 iterations.

Comment: @MikeWise line 20, plot(Y ~ X1, data = mydata), it starts to hand the console.

Comment: Very strange. How many rows in that array? Can you post the data somewhere?

Comment: data is in regression_auto.csv from https://sites.google.com/site/econometricsacademy/econometrics-models/linear-regression

Answer (score 5):

On Windows, I had to delete folder "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\RStudio-Desktop" to fix this issue.

Comment: This worked for me on Mac!! Except it was `/Users/[my username]/.rstudio-desktop` thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check your RStudio -> Preferences. Tab General, this option:

[image]

Probably, after running your code you have huge variables in memory and RStudio tries to save your workspace and it takes time.

Comment: No, I turned it to 'Never', but issue still there

Comment: Same here, I have set it to 'Never' and my session just sits on "Quitting R Session" indefinitely. In my case, I believe this to be related to working through Git and that integration always becoming frozen, super annoying, I love RStudio but this type of issue is way too common and needs a ton of work, 4+ years later this type of issue still comes up all the time no matter what version of RStudio I'm on, kills so much of my time.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this answer for someone still looking for a solution. Task Manager >Processes >Apps >RStudio> right click >End Task. This is for windows and for Mac,force quit method should probably work! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. When trying to close RStudio, i stalled in "Quitting R Session", never stopped spinning, and the system memory kept increasing till almost all RAM was occupied. Killing the R session or Rstudio via the Task Manager, rebooting, .. nothing helped. Everytime i restarted RStudio, not a single command could be executed without entering immediately in the "Quitting R Session" situation again.

What helped is, when you restart RStudio, immediately go to menu Session | Terminate R and restart RStudio once more.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and tried every solution i found and nothing worked. The only thing that i came up with that worked was:

Step 1: Deleting the folder 'R' in C:\Users\ [username]\Documents\R and the .Rdata in 'Documents'

Step 2: Uninstalling Rstudio AND R.

Step 3: Reinstall both R and Rstudio and voilá.

Hope it helps someone after all this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, open "Activity Monitor" and double click on "Rstudio" and select "Force quit".