# R Studio Unresponsive

Tags: r, rstudio

The issue I have is R Studio being (pretty much) completely unresponsive. Codes are not being run and I am unable to create new projects, and R studio stalls out when trying to quit out, restarting, or terminating the session- please see screenshots. Literally nothing is working- I can't even open up a new, blank R script. I'm running R Studio on a 2015 MacBook. [R Studio Stalling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRl5f.png) Notice the console ">" status symbol is not present.

I have tried the following suggestions but none have worked:

1. reinstalling R and R studio
2. Deleting the folder:  /Users/[my username]/.rstudio-desktop --**** I CANNOT FIND THIS FOLDER- It doesn't exist???** suggestion from: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532328/couldnt-quit-r-session-or-couldnt-quit-rstudio`** [Folder missing!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJO71.png)
3. Loading the suggested code in Terminal: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio

Thanks so much for any insights,
LD

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac these may be hidden files, try cmd + shift + . to see those hidden files.
I had to uninstall R, R studio, delete all .rdata and workspace files from my active directory as well as the .rstudio-desktop folder from my home directory as well